# Turn emoji into Javascript Encoding?

Tags: javascript, encoding, emoji

Is there any function or something that I can use to convert an emoji or something into the Javascript Encoding equivalent? For example, if I have a variable that contains "", I want to be able to convert it to its corresponding javascript encoding, like "\ud83d\udc4d". Any way this can be accomplished?

Comment: `""` is valid javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **punycode** library.`npm i punycode` or visit https://www.npmjs.com/package/punycode

for example.

```
   console.log(punycode.ucs2.decode('')); // to get corresponding like "\ud83d\udc4d"code
```

and

```
console.log('\ud83d\udc4d')
```

to get corresponding image/emoji;

You can visit http://speakingjs.com/es5/ch24.html and https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-unicode/ for more information.

---

**Update**

[image]

You can have refrence from

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_symbols.asp) here is the example.

```html
<p>I will display &#9786;</p>
```

```
<p>I will display &#9786;</p>
```

Comment: i need to convert \uD83D\uDE0A to emoji can you tell m how to do?

Comment: @Kapilsoni I have updated the answer according to you. I will recommend this way. You can have look it by running code .it is showing same emoji

Comment: :i think firstly we convert \uD83D\uDE0A to Dec right?

Comment: @Kapilsoni Hey i dont know if some function exist to convert that as when we convert `\uD83D\uDE0A` to dec it dont gave the dec number required for that same emoji. You can visit the link and search your emoji and you will find dec code you need

Comment: you can look output of \uD83D\uDE0A by console.log('\uD83D\uDE0A') and then choose that output like emoji from the link i provide

Comment: output is same as \uD83D\uDE0A  nothing changes

Comment: @Kapilsoni Did you wrote the same code ? `<p>I will display &#9786;</p>`

Comment: @Kapilsoni By visiting the link you will find table. Where you can find all such codes

Comment: yes i agree with you  but in mycase every time emojis is different not fixed?

Answer (score 0):

```
function emojiToUnicodeEscape(emoji) {
    return emoji
        .split('')
        .map(char => "\\u" + char.charCodeAt(0).toString(16))
        .join('');
}

const myEmoji = "";
const unicodeEscapeSequence = emojiToUnicodeEscape(myEmoji);
console.log(unicodeEscapeSequence);
```